# TypeError when doing struct.pack on an int?

Tags: python, minecraft

I am trying to implement [Server List Ping](http://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping) in Python. The specific packet structures are at the above link, and the types and generic packet structure are [here](http://wiki.vg/Protocol). My code is [here](http://pastebin.com/9UgWAG7y). But when I try to run that code, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ddos.py", line 6, in <module>
    handshakeBytes.append(pack('<i', 0x00))
TypeError: an integer is required
```

I also tried surrounding `0x00` with `int()`, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the page: https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html
struct.pack(fmt, v1, v2, ...) - Return a string containing the values v1, v2, ...

So you're trying to put string into byte array, which obviously won't work. Put your bytes into the array without using pack function or use:

```
handshakeBytes += pack(whatever)
```

notation.

Comment: Hmm, thanks! But how would I get the correct endianesses for the non `VarInt`s? (i.e. the string and the unsigned short)

Comment: Ahh, didn't catch that.